# how can I tell if any mockito object was created

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Is there a way to tell if any mockito object was created in test?
In our tests Mockito objects are saved on session, and then should be removed from session in loop:

```
    MockUtil mockUtil = new MockUtil();
    for (Object object : sessionObjects) {
        if (mockUtil.isMock(mock) || mockUtil.isSpy(mock)) {
            toClean.add(serviceClass);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to avoid this loop and check if any mock object was created?

Comment: This seems like a code smell, why does this need to be done at all, why can't they just be GCed?

Comment: if they are not cleaned, later on they might be (mistakenly) used by the next test in the test suite. Is there a better way to clean mocks after every test?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of your test suite. Can you [edit] to include an [mcve]? You don't have to include the entire suite, just a basic structure to show how you're setting up your session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito doesn't keep around a global list of all mocks, as mocks are intended to be short-lived objects that are replaced before every test—often by a @Before method, [MockitoJUnitRunner](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html), or [MockitoRule](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html). (Keeping a global list may interfere with the mocks' garbage collection.) If a test doesn't replace and prepare its entire environment before starting, that's usually the fault of the test being started, not the test that didn't clean up.

If you use Mockito as part of a long-lived server started once per test suite (or otherwise have a long-lived container-injected mock), that's a good use for [`Mockito.reset`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#reset(T...)) listed as [item #17 in the Mockito docs](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17). `reset` will clear all expectations and recorded invocations for a mock, which is good for clearing out a long-lived object at the beginning or end of a test. It is frequently and wrongly used to clear expectations in the middle of a test that should be split into two tests; be careful not to overuse it for that purpose.

**Aside:** You probably shouldn't use [MockUtil](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/internal/util/MockUtil.html); it's in an internal package. Prefer [Mockito.mockingDetails(Object)](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mockingDetails(java.lang.Object)) instead, as in [the Mockito docs as item #26](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mocking_details).

Comment: thank you, Jeff. It probably makes sense to invoke Mockito.reset before mocks them from session - to avoid a memory leak